# Rigged object suddenly not rendering

Tags: rendering, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, parent

I've been working on this model for days, finally got the texture right and the rigging right (ish).  Until I started posing the rig, everything rendered beautifully.
Then I had a boatload of trouble with the rig caused by a very large cat, and I ended up having to unparent the mesh from the rig and re-parent it.  Ever since then, I have not been able to get the mesh to render.  Spent hours searching the internet looking for a solution but so far no suggestions have worked.  I'm using Blender 2.78 on a Macbook Pro.

[image: rigged object on left render on right]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the problem; somehow, under Duplication, I had Group chosen instead of None.

I blame the cat.

Comment: Bloody cats....

Answer (score 0):

-Have you given it a rendered material to render with?
-What about selecting the correct viewable scenes?
-Does it render in resting pose?
-can you see the material pose scene, try a different render other than cycles too.

Comment: Yes, I have.  It shows up in Texture Paint mode.

Comment: Just tried to put the rig back into the resting pose, it won't. (ALT R,S,G, yes?)

Comment: Oh, by the way, using Blender render; boss no cycles. :)